# Powershell Remoting CredSSP Error

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, credssp

I was getting this error below:

"Connecting to remote server TESTSERVER01 failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request.     Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests.      Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM."

I've following the hundreds of fixes online for this. Nothing works, ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The fix which worked on all my Windows 2012 servers was....

1. Enabled Powershell Remoting.
2. Enabled Credentials Negotiating on both servers.
3. Set trusted hosts to *.mydomain.
4. **Crucial: GPEDIT.MSC -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Remote Management -> WinRM Service.  Key = Allow remote server management through WinRm be set to '*' not empty!**